# Best way to link to polymorphic record, and how to prevent destruction of Pictures if it's set as User's profile image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a polymorphic pictures table and I need to link user's profile_image to pictures id... so I have this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :attached_item, dependent: destroy

  belongs_to :profile_image, class_name: 'Picture'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, allow_destroy: true,
                                reject_if: proc { |attr| attr[:attachment].nil? }

  after_save :update_profile_image

  def update_profile_image
    if profile_image.nil? and pictures.size > 0
    pictures.each do |pic|
      next if pic.marked_for_destruction?
      self.update_attribute(:profile_image_id, pic.id)
    end
  end
end

class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :attached_item, polymorphic: true

  has_one :profile_image, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :profile_image_id

  mount_uploader :attachment, #carrierwave uploader
end
```

Pictures are sent through user form using `fields_for :pictures`.

1. I need to link `profile_image` to one record of `Picture` class if no `profile_image` is set yet.
2. I need to prevent destroying a nested picture if it is an user's profile image.

When i save my user form, it updates profile_image_id to pictures.id, but i'm not being able to prevent its destruction.
Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the use of avatar_id in User model

Comment: @gates I've updated the question, avatar_id is now profile_image_id... is more comprehensible now?